# provide current location and nearby markers

Tags: javascript, api, dictionary, location

Can we use another method for **geolocating** latitude and longitude in javascript other than  `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`

Comment: Not as far as I know, but do you need something else more special than what it already does?

Comment: actually the navigator method have been depreciated by map api and it only allows for localhost and https so just want to ask whether the latitude and longitude can be fetched using php ? and if u have another method in javascript then its most welcome @catalin lancu

Comment: I see. I did indeed used this on a more complex js app, but it was packaged into an Android App, so it was technically `localhost` for me. There seems to be something like a plugin for Php for this at http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php, but I am not sure how would that work. After all, the location is something the device would provide (front-end) and the server should not have any way of knowing where the device is located beforehand.

Comment: I have recently used that JavaScript on my Android phone, although it worked it was useless because it will only work when there are no buildings near - which are not sufficently large to upset my TomTom satnav.

Comment: thanx for that plugins @catalin lancu